# Handling function in Go that receives a Javascript object (using socket.io)

Tags: javascript, jquery, go, websocket, socket.io

I have the following code from the client (written in jQuery):

```
$("#send").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var content = $("#msg-content").val().trim();
    //emit a socket, sending an object to the server
    socket.emit("createMessage", {
        user: "Lam",
        content: content
    });
    $("#msg-content").val('');
});
```

And the code from server

```
import "github.com/googollee/go-socket.io"

Server.On("connection", func(so socketio.Socket) {
        logger.Info("on connection")
        //what parameter and its type should I put inside the func?
        so.On("createMessage", func(type?) {

        })
})
```

My question is how can I pass the js object from the client into the "createMessage" event?

I would really appreciate any help. Sorry I can't indent the code.

Comment: Which socketio package are you using? When asking about Go code, include your import statements.

Comment: Just edited the code

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in the example about [`Server Side`](https://github.com/googollee/go-socket.io#sending-ack-with-data-from-server-to-client) the function expects a string. Additionally the object you're referring to is a JSON object - so it's string. I'd imagine you'd want to unmarshal (decode) that JSON string, in order to do something with it. I'd venture, what you need would be something like the following:

```
import "github.com/googollee/go-socket.io"

Server.On("connection", func(so socketio.Socket) {
        logger.Info("on connection")
        //what parameter and its type should I put inside the func?
        so.On("createMessage", handlePayload)
})

func handlePayload(msg string) {
    // do something with the JSON string in the msg
}
```